Get User access token from within ActivityHandler - Botframework Python SDK
A Teams Bot application has been developed using the Bot Framework Python SDK (v4.14.4), where BotFrameworkAdapter and an extended ActivityHandler class have been properly initialized. The bot is functioning correctly, allowing chat interactions and responses.
The goal is to retrieve the user access token from the incoming request (the token included in the header when a user sends a message) to make an external API call. However, only the TurnContext object is available in the on_turn or on_message_activity methods of the ActivityHandler.
In the app.py file, the routing method for /api/messages is as follows:
# bot_framework_adapter and activity_handler are initialized at the global level

async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:
    # .. some other logic
    auth_token = req.headers.get("Authorization", "")
    response = await bot_framework_adapter.process_activity(activity, auth_token, activity_handler.on_turn)

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/archive/samples/python/11.qnamaker
My application almost implements the above sample reference, except for the on_message_activity on the BOT/ActivityHandler.
Currently, I have overriden process_activity and process_activity_with_identity on the BotFrameworkAdapter class in my extended class and added a new key-value pair for this auth_token on context.turn_state dictionary.
But is it possible to access/reconstruct this auth_token within the ActivityHandler methods (maybe using the TurnContext object), or is there a recommended workaround for making an external API call with the same user authorization used for the Bot?
Note: I am consuming this Bot through Microsoft Teams application using the Azure Bot service. So, the auth_token I am referring earlier is the token being sent from the teams application.
Thanks in advance.

In the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK (Python), you can access the user’s access token from within the ActivityHandler by retrieving the conversation or token information passed within the incoming activity. Specifically, you can access the user’s access token by looking at the Authentication header of the incoming activity. The token can be extracted from the turn_context during the on_message_activity or on_event_activity methods by calling the turn_context.activity object and checking for authentication tokens.

on_message_activity: This method is called when a message activity is received. Here, we retrieve the user's access token.
get_user_access_token: This method checks the incoming activity to see if it contains the access token, typically found in the channel_data under the OAuth key (this can depend on how OAuth is set up in your bot's configuration).
